# how to show BlackTranslucent StatusBar in movie player?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, ios-simulator

I have a MPMoviePlayerController view added as a subview on my ViewController.

I want to show BlackTranslucent StatusBar along with player controls. I have done the following:

in viewdidload:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

movieplayercontroller function:

```
self.player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;        

self.player.fullscreen = TRUE;      
self.player.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;   

player.view.frame = [self.view bounds];
[player prepareToPlay]; 
[player play];
```

but it's not comming up.

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is `self.player.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;`

i use just this code and i get the BlackTranslucent StatusBar

```
        [player setFullscreen:YES];

        // May help to reduce latency
        [player prepareToPlay];
        [player play];
```